# Cos product identity

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Show that `/prod_k=1^n cos (x/2^k) =sin x /(2^n sin(x/2^n))`
I have tried with werner on `prod_k=1^n cos (x/2^k)sin(x/2^n)` and with eulero but it just brings me nowhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: Multiply the left-hand side on the right by $\sin(x/2^n)$.  Using the identity $\sin(2t)=2\sin t \cos t$, we get $\left(\prod_1^{n-1}\cos(x/2^k)\right)(1/2)\sin(x/2^{n-1})$. Now use the last sine obtained to "suck up" $\cos(x/2^{n-1})$ and continue.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas now is clear

Comment: You are welcome. The $\cos(x/2^k)$ terms get chewed up one at a time, leaving a $1/2$ term behind. This continues until the end, when we are left with $\sin x$ multiplied by a bunch of $1/2$.